# "undefined reference to __dso_handle" while linking static library with -nostdlib

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

To harden my shared library (avoid library injection), I built my shared library with -nostdlib.
The shared library depended on a static library (libfreeimage.a)
Things went wrong during the linking process:

g++ -shared -fPIC -nostdlib a.o b.o c.o -o libfreeimage.a -o libmy_so.so

the errors were as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /path/linux_arm64/libfreeimage.a(ImfMultiPartInputFile.o): relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against external 
symbol `__dso_handle' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
path/linux_arm6/libfreeimage.a(ImfMultiPartInputFile.o):ImfMultiPartInputFile.cpp:(.text.startup+0x110): more undefined refer
ences to `__dso_handle' follow
```

Were there any gcc flags I have missed, such as -lgcc ?

Comment: Why do you use gcc for building and linking c++ files? This causes the error.

Comment: typo error, it was g++